# In-app purchase and clear data

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using in-app purchase in my application and storing the products in PurchaseDatabase as shown in sample billing application.

But, when I clear data from application settings for my application, in-app purchased items are deleted. Is it normal behaviour for all other applications using in-app or somehow I should prevent products to be deleted after clear data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS to retrieve what items were purchased. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type) for details.